# How to call an ID specifically within the parent element and ignore all other elements with the same ID (using pure JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm fairly new to JS. So, pardon me for asking such stupid question.

I want to implement a Read more/ less button based on [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp).

This worked perfectly fine, because it had unique id. But when I implement this in a multiple read more blocks with *same id*, it triggers only the first element.

I have two div with id `card1` and `card2` under the parent div of class `wrapper`. I want to show clicked read more div (let say of `card1`) and hide the other div (`card2`) completely (and vice-versa).

Here's [**my code**](https://codepen.io/JD212121/pen/QWgvJyo).

As you can see, it works **perfectly fine** for the first div (`card1`), but due to the *contradiction of using same id*, it doesn't work for other div.

It is possible, to **call id specifically of parent div where the button is clicked and ignore the elements of other div with the same id**. Is there any other simple way to solve my problem?

So far I don't know jQuery, so, solving the problem with pure JS will be very helpful.

Thank you.

```js
function myFunction(t) {
  var x = document.getElementById(t.id).parentNode;
  var y = x.parentNode;
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
    y.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    y.style.visibility = "hidden";
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
#more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="card1">
    <h2>Read More Read Less </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
  </div>
  <div id="card2">
    <h2>Read More Read Less 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique.

Comment: Search for __accordion__

Comment: In general Id should be unique, if you want them both to work with the same functionality and they already have the same css, its more reasonable to work with class instead of id, and do getElementsByClass(). If you still want the id it needs to have a different name

Comment: @Shai I suggest to delegate to the nearest container and use classList.contains. I personally use querySelectorAll rather than getElementsByClassName

Comment: @Shai I have tried to implement class as well. I ran them in a loop and it expands all read more blocks. But in that case, I was unable to hide the other child elements and show only the clicked read more div.

Comment: @mplungjan Sure, can work with that too to be more precise, but still they need to be a bit more unique than the same id, in this case I would extract the styles into class, "more" and class "expend" for example, and just add expend the selected div btw

Comment: @mplungjan Can you please provide an example, I'm really eager to try your solution.

Comment: @saravanapriyan Thanks for your help, but unfortunately accordion can't solve my problem, because i want to use it in my blog post rather than FAQ section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things

- IDs need to be unique, use a class
- It is not recommended to use inline event handlers  - your code is a perfect target for delegation

So I

1. Created a hide class and added it to what needed to be hidden from start
2. TOGGLE the class
3. Change the text based on the presence of the hide class

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button"); // in case you want something inside the button
  if (tgt && tgt.classList.contains("readMoreBtn")) {
    const parent = tgt.closest(".card");
    const dots = parent.querySelector(".dots");
    const moreText = parent.querySelector(".more");
    dots.classList.toggle("hide")
    moreText.classList.toggle("hide")
    tgt.innerHTML = moreText.classList.contains("hide") ? "Read more" : "Read less";
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  color: #eee;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="card" id="card1">
    <h2>Read More Read Less </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more hide">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
    <button type="button" class="readMoreBtn">Read more</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="card2">
    <h2>Read More Read Less 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more hide">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
    <button type="button" class="readMoreBtn">Read more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```